# Map-side join with Hadoop Streaming

Tags: join, hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I have a file in which each line is a record. I want all records with the same value in a certain field (call if field A) to go to the same mapper. I have heard this is called a Map-Side Join, and I also heard that it's easy if the records in the file are sorted by what I call field A.

If it would be easier, the data could be spread across multiple files, but each file sorted on field A.

Is this right? How do I do this in with streaming? I'm using Python. A assume it's just part of the command I use to start Hadoop?

Comment: I'm still keen on knowing the answer. Should I clarify anything?

Answer (score 0):

What is the real justification for wanting only certain records to go to certain mappers? If what you want out of this is the final result to be 3 output files (one with all A, another with all B, last with all C), you can accomplish that with multiple reducers. Need to know what you really want to accomplish.